# How do I test a FactoryGirl generated user with Sorcery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot, sorcery

I've tried all sorts of different things, and I can't get the following to work.

Here is my factory:

```ruby
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    username              "user"
    email                 "user@email.com"
    password              "userpass"
    password_confirmation "userpass"
  end
end
```

And here is my test:

describe "With valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

```
  before do
    fill_in 'Username',   with: user.username.upcase
    fill_in 'Password',   with: user.password
    click_button 'Sign in'
    binding.pry
  end
```

**edit:** The `binding.pry` shows me that `user.password` is `nil`. Hardcoding the password seems to work, even though it's not as nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but it requires hard-coding in the password:

Here is my factory:

```ruby
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    username              "user"
    email                 "user@email.com"
    password              "userpass"
    password_confirmation "userpass"
  end
end
```

And here is my test:

describe "With valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

```
  before do
    fill_in 'Username',   with: user.username
    fill_in 'Password',   with: "userpass"
    click_button 'Sign in'
  end
```